# how to get nested child which placed on top in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to change image icon (book) on click on input textbox. for getting that image am using this approach

```
 var x = that.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].firstChild;
```

But unable to get that. I have two input groups. when click on any input it should change only the book icon that is placed in its group. Kindly help how to solve this.

```js
function show(that) {
  var x = that.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].firstChild;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="toggle-check-group" style="background:#bdeabd">
    <span>
        <a>
            <img src="book.png" /> Book
        </a>
    </span>
    <br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
  </div>

  <br /><br />
  <div class="toggle-check-group" style="background:#f9b9b9">
    <span>
        <a>
            <img src="book.png" /> Book
        </a>
    </span>
    <br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
    <label><input onclick="show(this)" /></label><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid using `Element.parentNode.parentNode.paren.....` use `Element.closest("selector")` instead.

Comment: Then use `querySelector("img")` to get the descendant `img` rather than trying to find your way back down the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delegate and navigate using closest

I use textContent here but gave you how to change the image

you could also toggle two images

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", e => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches("input")) return;
    tgt.closest("div").querySelector("span a").textContent = ""
    // tgt.closest("div").querySelector("span a img").src="otherbook.jpg"
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="toggle-check-group" style="background:#bdeabd">
    <span><a></a></span><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
  </div>

  <br /><br />
  <div class="toggle-check-group" style="background:#f9b9b9">
    <span><a></a></span><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
    <label><input/></label><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```